# Flex Box Media Query Difficulty

Tags: html, css, flexbox

From min-width of 769px to 1025px, I want the 3rd figure on a new line while the first and second figures remain on the top line taking up equal space. I'm attempting flex boxes in css. How do I get this to work?

```
<div class="mid-col-section-2">
<figure><a href="#"><img src="images/landscape-maintenance.jpg" alt="landscape" height="300"><figcaption>Landscape Maintenance</figcaption></a></figure>
<figure><a href="#"><img src="images/landscape-design.jpg" alt="landscape" height="300"><figcaption>Landscape Design</figcaption></a></figure>
<figure><a href="#"><img src="images/masonry-design.jpg" alt="landscape" height="300"><figcaption>Masonry Design</figcaption></a></figure>
```

```
.mid-col-section-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mid-col-section-2 figure a {
  color: black; 
}

figcaption {
  text-align: left; 
}

@media (min-width: 1025px){

  .mid-col-section-2 {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 60px 10px 60px;
  }

  figcaption {
    text-align: center; 
  }

  .mid-col-section-2 figure {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might want to brush up on flexbox properties. You're throwing a lot in there that you probably don't actually want.

I revised your markup since the `<figure>` tag has default styles applied to it by the browser:

```
<div class="mid-col-section-2">
    <div class="mid-section">
        <img width="100%" src="http://jonvilma.com/images/landscape-3.jpg" alt="landscape"><figcaption>Landscape Maintenance</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="mid-section">
        <img width="100%" src="http://jonvilma.com/images/landscape-3.jpg" alt="landscape"><figcaption>Landscape Design</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="mid-section">
        <img width="100%" src="http://jonvilma.com/images/landscape-3.jpg" alt="landscape"><figcaption>Masonry Design</figcaption>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I tidied up your CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1025px){
  .mid-col-section-2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .mid-section {
    margin: 0;
    width: 45%;
  }
```

Here's the result: https://jsfiddle.net/qdoxL23p/embedded/result/

Comment: Nevermind. I added flex-wrap in 1025px min width and it worked. Thank you